# avoid repetative calling set method for java class with similar fields

Tags: java, set

I was given a class (which I could not change) with a lot of fields of String, each of them have a set method.

```
public class C {
  private String fieldA,
  private String fieldB,
  ...
  public void setFieldA(String s) {
    this.fieldA = s;
  }
  public void setFieldB(String s) {
    this.fieldB = s;
  }
  ...
}
```

I need to write code to create an instance of the class and initialize it with a json object (which will have value for some or all of the fields).

The json is very simple and looks like:

{"fieldA":"valueA", "fieldB":"valueB"..... }

I know I could write something like below for every field:

```
if (myJsonObj.containsKey("fieldA"){
    myInstance.setFieldA(myJsonObj.get("fieldA").toString());
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a smarter way I could do this, since the number of fields could be up to about thirty. Instead of repeating the above code thirty times (and the only thing different between each is "fieldA" in the above code).

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to look into using an existing json parser such as Gson since they do this for you. You said you could not modify the class, but can you add annotations to the class?

Comment: Hi, MTilsted : sorry that I didn't understand your comment. I can parse the JSONObject with no problem. The issue is I don't know a generic way of calling the corresponding set method as if the method is a variable (based on the key).

Comment: The point is if you use something like GSon, you just give it your json file, and it will return your java object, where all the fields are set with the values from the json file. This works best if the fields in you classes are the same, as the names in the json field so Gson can do the mapping automaticly. Otherwise you will have to use some kind of annotations so gson knows how to map your json fields to java fields.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for reflection to me.  Everything except the bit marked with "Reflection" is here solely to make this an SSCCE.  You'll likely have your own way to track which methods are available or whatever.  Take a look at the following site for  an (IMHO) excellent guide (I am not affiliated with the site in any way): [Guide to Java Reflection](https://www.baeldung.com/java-reflection)

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Test {

    private String fieldA;
    private String fieldB;
    private String fieldC;
    private String fieldD;
    private String fieldE;
    public String getFieldA() {
        return fieldA;
    }
    public void setFieldA(final String fieldA) {
        this.fieldA = fieldA;
    }
    public String getFieldB() {
        return fieldB;
    }
    public void setFieldB(final String fieldB) {
        this.fieldB = fieldB;
    }
    public String getFieldC() {
        return fieldC;
    }
    public void setFieldC(final String fieldC) {
        this.fieldC = fieldC;
    }
    public String getFieldD() {
        return fieldD;
    }
    public void setFieldD(final String fieldD) {
        this.fieldD = fieldD;
    }
    public String getFieldE() {
        return fieldE;
    }
    public void setFieldE(final String fieldE) {
        this.fieldE = fieldE;
    }

    private static final char[] chars = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'};
    private static final String[] values =
        {"valueA", "valueB", "valueC", "valueD", "valueE"};
    private static final Class<?>[] types = {String.class};




    public static void main(final String[] args)
        throws SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalArgumentException,
        IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {

        // Reflection setting values - everything else is here solely to make this an SSCCE
        final Test test = new Test();
        final Class<Test> clazz = Test.class;
        for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            final String name = "setField" + chars[i];
            final Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod(name, types);
            final Object[] params = {values[i]};
            method.invoke(test, params);
        }
        // End of reflection


        System.out.println(test.getFieldA());
        System.out.println(test.getFieldB());
        System.out.println(test.getFieldC());
        System.out.println(test.getFieldD());
        System.out.println(test.getFieldE());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I'm looking for. As shown in your code, in my own code, I only need to define the array and loop through it to invoke the method.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Chris Parker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6894838/chris-parker).
Here is my final code based on his original code. Because there are many String fields in the class and it might change in the future, so using reflect makes the update/change very easy: I only need to change the String Array.

The given class is like below (only String fields and their set methods are shown):

```
public class MyClass {
  private String fieldA,
  private String fieldB,
  ...
  public void setFieldA(String s) {
    this.fieldA = s;
  }
  public void setFieldB(String s) {
    this.fieldB = s;
  }
  ...
}
```

The method to set the value of those string fields using a JSONObject input to an instance of C:

```
public void fillClassStringFields(MyClass c, JSONObject input) {
        String[] names = {"FieldA","FieldB",...};
        Class<MyClass> clazz = MyClass.class;
        Class<?>[] types = {String.class};
        for(int i = 0; i< names.length;i++) {
            String name = names[i].toString();
            String methodName = "set" + name;
            if(input.containsKey(name)) {
                try {
                    Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, types);
                    method.invoke(c, input.get(name).toString());
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```